# Oracle to many Same Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, oracle, relational-database

I have to pull records that have location ids spanning multiple contract ids, also excluding duplicates. Below is a sample table. The second table is the query with my desired result.

```
| CONTRACT ID | LOCATION ID | CONTRACT NAME | CONTRACT DATE | CONTRACT STATUS |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  CT1          |  100      | MICROSOFT     | 12/09/2029    |   PENDING        
|  CT1          |  100      | MICROSOFT     | 12/09/2029    |   APPROVED       
|  CT3          |  155      | YAHOO         | 02/03/2030    |   EXPIRED       
|  CT4          |  180      | ADOBE         | 02/03/2030    |   IN LITIGATION       
|  CT4          |  180      | ADOBE         | 02/03/2030    |   APPROVED       
|  CT5          |  199      | YAHOO         | 02/03/2030    |   PENDING       
|  CT6          |  100      | GOOGLE        | 10/23/2028    |   PENDING       
|  CT7          |  155      | UBER          | 05/15/2027    |   PENDING       
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

| CONTRACT ID   | LOCATION ID  |
----------------------------------
|  CT1          |  100         |
|  CT6          |  100         |
|  CT3          |  155         |
|  CT7          |  155         |
-----------------------------------
```

I tried to running this query but it also includes records both CT4 Adobe contracts which features a location id that does not span multiple contract ids.
Even if I put a distinct at the beginning of the query, that contract CB4 id/location id pair should not be part of the results.

```
SELECT contract_id, location_id from random_table where location_id in
    (SELECT location_id FROM random_table
    where (location_id is not null)
    group by location_id  having count( location_id) > 1 )
    group by contract_id, location_id
    order by location_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like following using `WHERE EXISTS`.

```
SELECT contractid, 
       locationid 
FROM   [youtable] y 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 
               FROM   [youtable] TY 
               WHERE  TY.locationid = Y.locationid 
                      AND TY.contractid <> Y.contractid) 
GROUP  BY contractid, 
          locationid 
ORDER  BY locationid
```

[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/RHRSO58811)

Edit:

If you  want to find such location id, you can use following query.

```
SELECT ty.locationid 
FROM   tablename TY 
       INNER JOIN tablename y 
               ON TY.locationid = Y.locationid 
                  AND TY.contractid <> Y.contractid 
GROUP  BY ty.locationid
```

Comment: One more question. So I would imagine for the 2nd query, if I changed the condition of the 2nd query from <> to =, then the results should change to the opposite case, where contract ids are also the same. However does seem to be working that way.

Comment: In that case you will get every location id, it will become like select location from table

Answer (score 0):

You can try below - using correlated subquery

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b782ea0cc423e12b3c6d0f88932979b3)**

```
select distinct location_id, contractid
from tablename a
where exists (select 1 from tablename b where a.location_id=b.location_id
having count(distinct b.contractid)>1)
```

OUTPUT:

```
LOCATIONID  contractid
100           CT1
155           CT3
100           CT6
155           CT7
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Giving it a shot

Comment: Thanks again. That query runs but takes a little while